# Bash command line arguments, replacing defaults for variables

Tags: bash, variables, command-line-arguments, default

I have a script which has several input files, generally these are defaults stored in a standard place and called by the script.

However, sometimes it is necessary to run it with changed inputs.

In the script I currently have, say, three variables, $A $B, and $C. Now I want to run it with a non default $B, and tomorrow I may want to run it with a non default $A and $B.

I have had a look around at how to parse command line arguments:

*[How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)*

How do I deal with having some set by command line arguments some of the time?

I don't have enough reputation points to answer my own question. However, I have a solution:

*[Override a variable in a Bash script from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609668/override-a-variable-in-a-bash-script-from-the-command-line/4610469#4610469)*

```
#!/bin/bash
a=input1
b=input2
c=input3
while getopts  "a:b:c:" flag
do
    case $flag in
        a) a=$OPTARG;;
        b) b=$OPTARG;;
        c) c=$OPTARG;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: You can use `getopts` for this purpose. There are many tutorials, something like http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html can be useful for a start.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this on the questions I linked.

I was wondering if there is some standard way to have command arguments overwrite variables. For example when defining functions in python it is possible to set a default value.

I can see that with an if check I could replace the default with the command line argument, but was unsure if there was a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 92):

You can do it the following way. See *[Shell Parameter Expansion](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)* on the Bash man page.

```
#! /bin/bash

value=${1:-the default value}
echo value=$value
```

On the command line:

```
$ ./myscript.sh
value=the default value
$ ./myscript.sh foobar
value=foobar
```

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using command line arguments to overwrite default values, you can also set the variables outside of the script. For example, the following script can be invoked with `foo=54 /tmp/foobar` or `bar=/var/tmp /tmp/foobar`:

```
#! /bin/bash
: ${foo:=42}
: ${bar:=/tmp}
echo "foo=$foo bar=$bar"
```

Comment: I thought about this, however the script I am editing is for people with even less familiarity than myself. I want to make it as simple as possible, and I think command line arguments are somthing they are more familiar with.