# Passing variables from CLI to bash script

Tags: bash

I am wondering about some use case with bash script. Imagine that user type:

```
./my_script.sh INSTALL=FALSE
```

and then package is installed without any dependencies or type `INSTALL=TRUE` and then package is installed with all dependencies.

Now the script should know that `INSTALL=FALSE` is default way so it means that is okay to type just

```
./my_script.sh
```

but user needs to specify

```
./my_script.sh INSTALL=TRUE
```

if he wants to install package with all dependencies.

Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: Start by showing us what you're trying that _doesn't_ work.

Comment: BTW, it'd be easier for `INSTALL=TRUE ./my_script.sh` to be how it's overridden, instead of `./my_script.sh INSTALL=true`. The first way the variable gets passed through the environment, the second way you have to parse it out from command-line arguments.

Comment: [bash command line arguments replacing defaults for variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319720/bash-command-line-arguments-replacing-defaults-for-variables)

Comment: [override a variable in a bash script from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609668/override-a-variable-in-a-bash-script-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Give the variable a default value in the script before you check arguments.

Comment: BTW, it would be better if you used standard argument formatting like `--install true/false`. Then you can process arguments with `getopts`.

Comment: For users who have the `-k` option enabled, `./my_script.sh INSTALL=TRUE` is equivalent to `INSTALL=TRUE ./my_script.sh`; a variable named `INSTALL` with a value `TRUE` is added to the environment in which `my_script.sh` executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your script to remember the config, you should create a config file with correct setting.

- If script ran without any argument, read config file.
- If config file doesn't exist, create it with `INSTALL=FALSE`
- If script was given an argument, overwrite new setting to config file.

If script ran without any argument, and config file doesn't exist, create a config file with `INSTALL=FALSE`

Comment: Having said "config file" what do you mean? I thought that I can put the variables inside of my_script.sh file which corresponds to FALSE or TRUE and then I call out them in CLI like in my previous post.

Comment: @sqr You can pass an argument(false/true) to your script, but does your script remember this setting next time? You can default your script to 'false', meaning you have to tell your script every time if you want 'true'. Or my suggestion is to write your current setting (either 'true' or 'false') to a config file. And have your script to read that config file every time. Then your script will default to whatever config file says.