# Override variables in AWK scripts in command line/mother scripts

Tags: bash, variables, awk, overwrite

If we have an AWK script (average.sh) like this and would like to use it to process a lot of inputfiles:

```
awk -F\" 'BEGIN{print}
  last != $4""$8 && last{
      print line,exp(C/D)
      C=D=0}
  { # This block process each line of infile
   C += log($(NF-1)+0)
   D++
   $(NF-1)=""
   line=$0
   last=$4""$8}
  END{ # This block triggers after the complete file read
       # to print the last average that cannot be trigger during
       # the previous block
      print line,exp(C/D)}' ${var2:=infile}
```

Now if we do

```
export var2="infile4" | sh average.sh
```

The "average.sh" still process "infile" instead of "infile4".

Following the best answers in [Override a variable in a Bash script from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609668/override-variable-in-bash-script-from-command-line)    , we try

```
var2=infile4 ./geometric_average_real
```

This give an error of "var2=infile: Command not found."

Our final goal is to write loops

```
for (X=1; X<=3; X++)

do

sh average.sh infile${X}

done
```

so this loop shall process

```
sh average.sh infile1
sh average.sh infile2
sh average.sh infile3
```

Comment: `export var2="infile4" | sh average.sh` should not use a pipe. That should be a semicolon separating the commands. The pipe is causing you problems because you are spawning sub-shells. Try without that.

Comment: `var2=infile4 ./geometric_average_real` should work fine in `bash` but might not work in other shells (almost certainly not in `sh`). Make sure you are trying with `bash` and not `sh` if you want `bash` semantics.

Comment: Using an argument like your goal should work fine if you use the positional parameter arguments in your shell script instead of named variables (like `var2`). Did you try that and have it not work somehow?

Comment: Yes Etan!  "export var2="infile4" ; sh average.sh"  works!

Comment: By the way, you don't need to write `$4""$8`. `$4 $8` will work just fine, as will `$4$8`. If `a` and `b` are two variables, `a b` is their string concatenation. Just watch out for awk's odd expression precedence for the invisible concatenation operator.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your average.sh script is working for a single infile, then just call it from another script with a list of files you would like to process:

```
#!/bin/bash

test -n "$1" || { echo "error, insufficient input"; exit 1; }

avgscript="/path/to/average.sh"

test -x "$avgscript" || { echo "error: required script `$avgscript` not found or not executable"; exit 1; }

for i in "$@"; do

    avgscript "$i"

done
```

Save that file as say `runavg.sh` and then simply call `runavg.sh file1 file2 file2`

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the comment!  However, if we don't put a file name right after .....print line,exp(C/D)}'  ,there will be an error message "awk: cmd. line 14   ^ unexpected newline or end of string".    I use "sh average.sh input.csv" in bash

Comment: Well, darn. Can you put you entire awk script inside the above script where it says `avgscript` in the `for` loop in `$( your awk script "$i" )` with I in double-quotes and make the substitution work?

Comment: `for i; do` will also loop over all the positional arguments.